# Driving a seven-segment LED display without interruption

Tags: microcontroller, i2c, timer, delay

Microcontroller drives 3 digits seven segment type LEDs sequentially.

```
while(1)
{
select left character
wait 5ms
select middle character
wait 5ms
select right character
wait 5ms
}
```

If I add extra 80-100ms delay in while(1), the blinking of the LEDs can be noticed by the eye or may stop momentarily.

```
while(1)
{
select left character
wait 5ms
select middle character
wait 5ms
select right character
wait 5ms

=> I2C read sensor(max 85ms)
//Similar operations can stop LED blinking
}
```

I want to read the temperature value from an SHT21 sensor and display the values on LEDs continuously. The sensor needs 85ms after write command for reading temperature value.

```
I2C read sensor
{ 
i2c_start;
i2c_write_command; //this trigger measurement
wait 85ms; //wait end of measurement

i2c_read; //Temperature value ready on chip, read it
i2c_stop;
}
```

I setup a timer for reading SHT21 about 1 second interval, but for the delay in the I2C transaction, I can't lock the microprocessor, so I can't use delay_ms command.

I can setup another timer which works about 85ms interval.
Maybe this will work, but the second timer may complicate the software, I am also concerned about this point.

What other approach can I use?

Comment: Perhaps your biological clock works faster than normal - the usual practice for numerical displays is an update rate roughly three updates per second (333ms) rather than 85ms. You could possibly improve resolution by averaging 4 measurements, and display that result.

Comment: @glen_geek he's not talking about changing the number every 85ms -- he's saying he needs to *stop the digit sequencing* for 85ms.  That's long enough you'd see the display blinking.

Comment: @glen_geek yes sure..

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to real-time programming.  There's an infinite number of things you can do: here's the three most popular:

- Update the display out of an ISR that's fired off every 5ms by a timer.  This is kind of cheating, using your interrupt controller as a rather poor RTOS.
- Make an event-driven task loop (a "superloop").  This is a pretty good way to deal with a lot of different event-servicing code that all takes about the same amount of time to run.
- Use an RTOS.

I don't recommend the ISR approach except in certain narrow circumstances -- it works, but only until the boss comes up with more features that just have to be implemented.

I'm not going to go into the RTOS approach because there's not room, you don't need it if those two functions are all you're going to implement, and because there's plenty of documentation on how to make it work.

For the code below, assume that `timer_ready_flag()` returns true the first time that it is called after the timer completes a 5ms waiting time, and false after that until the next time the timer pops off.

```
digit_count = 0
sensor_time = 0
while True:    # Note that we never return from this
  if not timer_ready_flag():
    # just spin
    continue
  if sensor_time == 0:
    send_sensor_read_command()  # I assume this is the 'transmit' you talked about
    sensor_time += 1
  elif sensor_time < 20:
    sensor_time += 1
  else
    read_sensor_value()
    sensor_time = 0

  deselect_digits()
  write_digit_pattern(digit_count)
  select_digit(digit_count)
  digit_count += 1
  if digit_count >= 3:
    digit_count = 0
```

Yes, this will complicate your code -- you have to make everything it does event-driven, and if you have some processor intensive long-running task that only happens every once in a while you have to either put up with it messing around with operation, or you need to break that task up into little chunks, or you have to use a preemptive RTOS.  But it's a very common way of writing embedded real-time code because for simple-enough systems it works great.

Comment: Your ISR idea about LED driving and RTOS comments are very good. But the pseudo code example is pretty complicated(a little diffucult to understand).

Comment: using such "small, homemade os" is quite usual thing in microcontrollers when driving a lot of different thinhs. eg. lcd, butto s

Comment: Task loops require you to think inside out from what you're used to when you can put each task to be done into a function.  So they're off-putting at first.  Feel free to do a web search on "superloop" or "task loop" plus "embedded" -- you should find examples, and possibly one that you like better than this.

Answer (score 1):

Have a single counter generating an interrupt every 5 ms, and incrementing a counter.

Looking at your code, you may only need, for instance, a count of 24 to give you a 120 ms cycle. Obviously you can modify any of these numbers to suit.

Then have a function for each task, so left digit, right digit, middle digit, command temp sensor to read, read sensor.

Then fire off the relevant function when the counter gets to the correct count.

0 - update left digit
1 - update middle digit
2 - update right digit
3 - command sensor
4 - update left digit
5 - update middle digit
6 - update right digit
7 -
8 - update left digit
...
...
20 - update left digit
21 - update middle digit
22 - update right digit
23 - read sensor

This timer controls your time critical functions. You can format the temperature read from the sensor in the foreground task, or in the few idle slots in this list, whichever you prefer.

You can use a fixed table like this if the loop is short, the tasks are few, so the job is manageable manually. The next step before you get to a real time operating system (RTOS) would be to have a list of event functions that reschedule themselves to run after some elapsed time. Here the 5 ms interrupt checks the first job on the queue to run whether it's due to run yet. If not, it does nothing. When a task reschedules itself, it examines the queue of tasks, and inserts itself into the correct time-ordered position. This way, the scheduler does not have to examine the whole queue, so it scales well with a large number of tasks. If you need a new task, or a new timing, then the changes are trivial, unlike the manual table where you have some rebuilding to do.

Comment: You suggest a counter which is Timer triggered. Each task has its own number and should work when it comes to its number. I've always been afraid if this number is omitted or doesn't occur :)

Comment: @BerkerIşık The only thing we have to fear is fear itself. If the number is omitted or doesn't occur, then we have a non-working program. I've written many non-working programs in my life. Then I've examined why they don't work, modified them and got a working program. That's called software development. Start with a clear strategy that allows you to reason about what ought to be happening, and a scaleable way to make it happen.